# finding the primary key of a record to be inserted

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I've a mysql database with a table that contains these fields: `matchID, userID, puzzleID`

where `match ID` is the primary key and it has been set to `auto increment`.

And as code is following as:

```
query = "INSERT INTO matches(UserID, PuzzleID) VALUES('" & UserID _
           & "','" & puzzleID & "')"
da.InsertCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
Try
  da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox(ex.Message)
  exit sub
End Try
```

And then I need to get the `MatchID` of the freshly inserted row for the next bit of processing.

My question is:

Is it possible to get the `primary key` of an `insert statement` when the primary key is not `explicitly` stated?

Comment: You can use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` to fetch the inserted id in mysql

Answer (score 1):

You could combine two sql statements in a single command and retrieve the result of the last statement with ExecuteScalar

```
query = "INSERT INTO matches(UserID, PuzzleID) VALUES(@uid, @pid);" & _ 
        "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"
Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", userID)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", puzzleID)
Dim result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

Notice that you should always use a parameterized query when submitting commands to your database backend. If you build your command text using string concatenation with user inputs you are exposed to Sql Injection and parsing problems.

Comment: thank you, does this mean I can do away with data adapters altogether?

Comment: Adapters are useful when you need to update many records in batch. For example when you have a grid and allow your user to freely change, insert and delete and don't want to immediately update your db until the user confirms its changes. If you have just one record to insert then you could execute the insert command directly.

Answer (score 0):

my sql provide last insert id using

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SELECT MAX query to display the number of the last ID inserted

```
 query = "SELECT MAX(matchID)"
```